# Duplicate digit when extracting digits from a string

Tags: python

Let's say I have the following string:

```
A12B2C6
```

And I want to extract the digits for one vector and the characters for another one so that the output is:

```py
['12', '2', '6']
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

I tried to do this with the following code:

```py
string = input()
digits = []
characters = []
for c in range(len(string)-1):
    if string[c].isdigit():
        if string[c].isdigit() and string[c + 1].isdigit():
            digits.append(string[c] + string[c + 1])
        else:
            digits.append(string[c])
    else:
        characters.append(string[c])

print(digits)
print(characters)
```

But the exit is being:

```py
['12', '2', '2']
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Comment: Use regular expressions.

Comment: The problem is that you process `12` twice. First when `c` points to `1` you append `12`. The next iteration points to `2` so it appends `2`.

Comment: And using `len(string)-1` means you never process the last character.

Comment: Also your algorithm won't work if the number can be more than 2 digits.

Comment: You don't process the last digit.

Comment: What if you run it with just `A12`? See how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has two problems:

1. You process 2-digit numbers twice. When `c == 1` you append `12`, and when `c == 2` you append `2`. It's not really duplicating digits; it's just a coincidence that the `2` after `B` is the same as the `2` in `12` after `A`.
2. `for c in range(len(string)-1):` means you never process the last character in the string; that's why there's no `6` in the result. It should be `range(len(string))`, but then you need to handle `c == len(string)-1` specially so you don't try to use `string[c+1]`.

You could solve the first problem by using a `while` loop instead of `for`, so you can increment `c` twice when you process a 2-digit number.

But it's simpler to do it  with regular expressions:

```
import re

digits = re.findall(r'\d+', string)
characters = re.findall(r'\D', string)
```

Comment: That doesn't explain why their code isn't working.

Comment: @PeterWood I've added a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Others have pointed out the issue, but here is an implementation that should produce the correct result.

EDIT: I assume the down votes are from those that prefer the regex solution.  The regex solution is great, but OP may also be interested in seeing something that works along the same lines as their attempt.

```
string = input()

digits = []
characters = []
current_digit = ""

for c in string:
    if c.isdigit():
        current_digit += c
    else:
        # Non-digits signal the end of the current digit
        if current_digit:
            digits.append(current_digit)
            current_digit = ""
        
        characters.append(c)

# May need to "flush" the current digit if at end of string
if current_digit:
    digits.append(current_digit)

print(digits)
print(characters)
```

Comment: You're right. It was good to have seen the solution to my problem from two perspectives. Both the solution with regex and yours are great and thanks to everyone's comments I was able to see where my mistake was being made.

Answer (score -2):

Something like this would work from your code:

```
text = input()
digits = []
characters = []
for char in text:
    if char.isdigit() and not char in digits:
        digits.append(char)
    elif not char.isdigit() and not char in characters:
        characters.append(char)
print(digits)
print(characters)
```

You could also use set() to remove duplicates

Comment: Please read the question carefully, the goal is to group up adjacent digits, e.g. `['12', '2', '6']`